# How to detect if a git clone failed in a bash script

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

How can I tell if a `git clone` had an error in a bash script?

```
git clone git@github.com:my-username/my-repo.git
```

If there was an error, I want to simply `exit 1`;

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here are some common forms. Which is the best to choose depends on what you do. You can use any subset or combination of them in a single script without it being bad style.

---

```
if ! failingcommand
then
    echo >&2 message
    exit 1
fi
```

---

```
failingcommand
ret=$?
if ! test "$ret" -eq 0
then
    echo >&2 "command failed with exit status $ret"
    exit 1
fi
```

---

```
failingcommand || exit "$?"
```

---

```
failingcommand || { echo >&2 "failed with $?"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: You might consider appending >&2 to the echo command to send it to stderr instead of stdout.  Otherwise perfect answer.  +1

Comment: When calling `exit`, `exit` without args is the same as `exit $?`.

Comment: @jordanm - Except in these examples, $? will be modified by the call to `echo` itself.  So a simple `exit` will exit with status zero.

Answer (score 14):

You could do something like:

```
git clone git@github.com:my-username/my-repo.git || exit 1
```

Or exec it:

```
exec git clone git@github.com:my-username/my-repo.git
```

The latter will allow the shell process to be taken over by the clone operation, and if it fails, return an error.  You can find out more about exec [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec).

Comment: Almost working, but how can I add an echo "ERROR message here" then run `exit 1`? I tried: `|| echo "ERROR message here" && exit 1` but it always exits, even on success. Thanks.

Comment: You need `failingcommand || { echo message && exit 1; }` because the `&&` does not bind stronger than the `||`. And then you better use `failingcommand || { echo message; exit 1; }`

Answer (score 6):

**Method 1:**

```
git clone git@github.com:my-username/my-repo.git || exit 1
```

**Method 2:**

```
if ! (git clone git@github.com:my-username/my-repo.git) then
    exit 1
    # Put Failure actions here...
else
    echo "Success"
    # Put Success actions here...
fi
```