# Test to determine if git clone command succeeded

Tags: git, bash, bitbucket

I tried to clone the git repository by passing the username, password. That was successful.

But what my intention is that I want to know whether the git clone command executed or not. 
If not, I would like to handle such kind of errors in shell script itself.

**My working shell script:**

```
cd ..
git clone https://username:password@bitbucket.org/username/repositoryname.git
cd repositoryname
git checkout branchname1
cd ..
mv repositoryname newfoldername
git clone https://username:password@bitbucket.org/username/respositoryname.git
cd repositoryname
git checkout branchname2
cd ..
mv repositoryname newfoldername
```

How do I test, in the script, whether these steps were successful?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The return value is stored in $?. 0 indicates success, others indicates error.

```
some_command
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo OK
else
    echo FAIL
fi
```

I haven't tried it with git, but I hope this works.

Answer (score 2):

```
if some_command
then
  echo "Successful"
fi
```

### Example

```
if ! git clone http://example.com/repo.git
then
  echo "Failed"
else
  echo "Successful"
fi
```

See [How to detect if a git clone failed in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793836).

Answer (score 0):

This one should work (Just put your script at the place marked "--- your script here ---" below):

```
#!/bin/bash

# call your script with set -e to stop on the first error
bash <<EOF
set -e
--- your script here ---
EOF

# test status: I don't want this part to stop on the first error,
# and that's why use the HERE document above to wrap a sub-shell for "set -e"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo success
else
  echo fail
fi
```

Alternatively, HERE document can be replaced by:

```
(
  set -e
  --- your script here ---
)
```

Comment: Thanks Robin for giving such a good solution for my problem.It's working fine for my script now.